# Redirected url after filling the form programatically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, webbrowser-control

i have a question about redirected url. I am filling a for automatically. After filling the form i submit the form and click the button. After that it rediects to a new page. I need that redirect url.

As example

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("myurl.com")

        For I As Integer = 0 To 500
            If webBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then Exit For
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next

        Dim elementLogin = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_identifier")
        If Not IsNothing(elementLogin) Then
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_identifier").SetAttribute("Value", "myemail")
        End If
        Dim elementPassword = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password")
        If Not IsNothing(elementLogin) Then
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password").SetAttribute("Value", "mypassword")
        End If
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_btn").Enabled = True
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_btn").InvokeMember("click")
```

I need the redirected url after click on the button. As it redirects to a new page after clicking the login button. Please help me out for this if it's possible
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `WebBrowser.URL` to get the webpage it is navigating to. This can cause problems, though, if you try to get the new URL before navigation has begun (meaning you will get the **current** URL).

Instead, try looping through all elements of the `WebBrowser.Document` matching the button id, and finally getting the `href` of the button:

```
Dim NextURL As String() = ""
For Each ele As HtmlElement In webBrowser1.Document.All
    If ele.GetAttribute("id") = "login_btn" then
        NextURL = ele.GetAttribute("href")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This will fire "no" exceptions and will work for several elements at once.  Alternatively, and maybe better for your one alone button, use:

```
Dim NextURL As String = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_btn").GetAttribute("href")
```

EDIT: As the `href` tag of the button seems empty, it is better to subscribe to the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event handler after redirection to get the new web adress through `WebBrowser.URL`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually ele.GetAttribute("href") is empty.

Comment: Is it empty or just "#"? This would indicate that there's javascript or else involved.

Comment: so the WebBrowser.URL is the old url

Comment: Actually there are some calculations using email id and password then it genrates an authorization code. so it redirects to the new url with that authorization code in params. I need to access that auth code

Comment: If this auth. code is in the URL parameters, you can still get it after page load, right? If it is not then you are being referred elsewhere and it will be hard to find.

Comment: Yes it is in parameters. But i have another question as i already used an event handeler on this webbrowser so the document comlpleted is always true. I am not being able to notufy when the document is completed

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have another question you should close this one (by mark-as-answer) and open another thread so you can explain your new question to us further. See you there!

Comment: Well the problem is not much solved. As  webBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete is always true so i wonder how you can notify..?

Comment: That is not the event handler, [this is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).